# What have the L-systems (Lindenmayer systems) been actually used for in biology?

Tags: theoretical-biology

From Wikipedia:

> An L-system or Lindenmayer system is a parallel rewriting system and a type of formal grammar.
>
> L-systems were introduced and developed in 1968 by Aristid Lindenmayer, a Hungarian theoretical biologist and botanist at the University of Utrecht. Lindenmayer used L-systems to describe the behaviour of plant cells and to model the growth processes of plant development.

I tried to find biological research that has actually used this system but I could not find any. Perhaps this is because I do not know biology that well.

Are these models important? Still taught?

They do produce pretty pictures (again from Wikipedia)

[image]

Comment: The Wikipedia article points (in the references at the end) at least to a potential impact in developmental biology with this book (which I haven't read): http://www.amazon.com/Lindenmayer-Systems-Theoretical-Computer-Developmental/dp/3642634745

Comment: BTW awesome images.

Comment: http://ftp.tuebingen.mpg.de/pub/kyb/bweber/papers_db/2001/Zamir/J%20Gen%20Physiol%202001%20Zamir.pdf

Comment: The main point is not that biologists do use l-systems in their research (although those interested in artificial life do), but that plant growth is (in mathematical sense) a l-system.

Comment: I've been considering using them to produce realistic branching in neural simulations, but I haven't actually implemented anything yet.

Comment: Great photos... here's a paper from Researchgate that may help you. I suggest reading the abstract + intro thoroughly and skimming over the paper. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/27481070_Derivation_of_L-system_Models_from_Measurements_Biological_Branching_Structures_Using_Genetic_Algorithms

Comment: Greatly suitable to proposed [bioinformatics](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/109245/bioinformatics)

Answer (score 2):

> Are these models important? Still taught?

**Yes!!** These models are *extremely* important, however, the application of L-systems most definitely isn't confined to just the scope of Biology. I myself first came across L-systems when taking Calculus in university, and then later in several Computer Science courses (I study [Bioinformatics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bioinformatics)).

**What's (probably) most significant to mention about L-systems is that they produce [fractals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractal)**, which is acheived by defining a [substitution system](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SubstitutionSystem.html) and utilizing [recursion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)).

Fractal mathematics can be used to describe extremely complex phenomena, starting with just a few simple rules and initial conditions (which is why it's so powerful/attractive to study). Also, fractals have the nickname of, "God's Thumbprint", or, "The Fingerprint of God", just from where they're found so prevalently in nature. To name a few, fractals can "easily" model:

- Coastlines
- Blood vessels
- Brain structure (neuronal connectivity)
- Plant foliage
- Lightning bolts
- Diamonds
- Snowflakes

> I tried to find biological research that has actually used this system but I could not find any.

As you can see, some of these examples *are* biologically related, however, **the use of L-Systems have been broadened to many other fields of science, such as mathematics ([coding theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coding_theory)) and theoretical computer science**.

Unfortunately, very rarely do biologists have the mathematical or algorithmic backgrounds to work with L-systems, since L-systems are more related to mathematics, algorithms and logic, than they are with (practiced) biology.